# Use of substr() on DataFrame column in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, substr, sparkr

I am using SparkR and want to use the `substr()` command to isolate the last character of a string that is contained in a column.  I can get `substr()` to work if I set the StartPosition and EndPosition to a constant:

```
substr(sdfIris$Species, 8, 8)
```

But when I try to set these parameters using a value sourced from the DataFrame:

```
sdfIris <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris)
sdfIris$Len <- length(sdfIris$Species)
sdfIris$Last <- substr(sdfIris$Species, sdfIris$Len, sdfIris$Len)
```

> Error in as.integer(start - 1) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'integer'

It seems that the result being returned from `sdfIris$Len` is perhaps a one-cell DataFrame, and the parameter needs an integer.

I have tried `collect(sdfIris$Len)`, but:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘collect’ for signature ‘"Column"’

This seems incongruous.  `substr()` seems to see `sdfIris$Len` as a DataFrame, but `collect()` seems to see it as a Column.

I have already identified a work-around by using `registerTempTable` and using SparkSQL's substr to isolate the last character, but I was hoping to avoid the unnecessary steps of switching to SQL.

How can I use SparkR `substr()` on a DataFrame column with dynamic Start and Finish parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not optimal but you can use `expr`:

```
df <- createDataFrame(
  sqlContext,
  data.frame(s=c("foo", "bar", "foobar"), from=c(1, 2, 0), to=c(2, 3, 5))
)

select(df, expr("substr(s, from, to)")) %>% head()

##   substr(s,from,to)
## 1                fo
## 2                ar
## 3             fooba
```

or `selectExpr`:

```
selectExpr(df, "substr(s, from, to)") %>% head()

##   substr(s,from,to)
## 1                fo
## 2                ar
## 3             fooba
```

as well as equivalent SQL query.

Comment: thanks @zero323!  That will work for now - at least I don't have to registerTempTable() first.  I will try to enquire of the Spark project whether my need is a bug or a feature request.

Comment: Feature request. There is no dataframe API with dynamic offsets on JVM do it couldn't be exposed in R.